# header('Location:') не перенаправляет

Tags: php, header

Если кратко то есть функция

```
static function ErrorPage404()
{
    $host = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/404';
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    header('Location:'.$host.'');
    exit();
}
```

В нужный момент ее вызываю и на локальном хостинге все работает... Но при переносе срабатывают все заголовки, кроме location ... 
Подозреваю что дело в настройке сервера (возможно из за SSL, включен 301 редирект с http на https) но не могу докопаться...

Читал подобные проблемы, но решения так и не нашел...
Вот что пробовал:
Установил значение output_buffering = On,ob_start(),ob_end_flush();

Вот что выдает браузер(название сайта заменил):

```
Request URL:https://site.ru/avtolombard/asd
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Response Headers
view source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:14247
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sat, 04 Mar 2017 19:36:07 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=3, max=100
Location:http://site.ru/404
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

В действительности оказалось, что не работает Location с заголовком 404... Спасибо @Qwertiy за совет по поводу неудобства для пользователя. По итогу добавил пару условий в маршрутизатор и выдаю контент 404-й станицы с заголовками 404, не меняя URL

Comment: Location анализируется только в случае кодов 301, 302 и еще некоторых, которые я не помню наизусть (возможно, всех 3хх, знания меня подводят). Зачем вам вообще выдавать 404 и тут же редиректить? Вам нужно прямо сказать пользователю, что страницы не существует.

Comment: 404 надо отдавать без редиректа. Через `readfile` например

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такое подозрение, что заголовок `location` работает только с трёхсотой группой кодов. Вроде 404 надо отдавать прям страницей ошибки, а не пытаться туда упихать редирект.

В принципе можно попробовать

```
Refresh: 3; URL=http://site.ru/404
```

Но вообще, это плохая идея, портить адрес страницы. Вот перепечатывал пользователь какой-то url, опечатался в одной букве и теперь ему всё вводить заново? Вместо того, чтобы просто исправить?

Comment: Действительно убрал заголовки 404 и все заработало.Как предлагаете сделать? Не делать редирект, а просто выдавать 404 заголовки и контент соответствующий??

Comment: @ДанилШуваев, да именно так - соответствующий контент 404й страницы без редиректа.

Answer (score 2):

404 следует отдавать без редиректа, через `readfile` или `include`, например.

```
static function ErrorPage404()
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    include('path/to/404.php');
    exit();
}
```

*Наличие редиректа в любом случае предполагает `3xx` статус.

Если же вебсервер пропускает `404` совместно с `Location` - у браузера нет никаких причин для перехода.*

Comment: Да, уже разобрались что не работает Location с 404 заголовком.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то подобное видел. Дело было в `exit()`, он по разному ведет себя на разных серверах. Возможно дело в *php* или в настройках.

Может попробовать в конце `return` ? Это правильней.